# ASP.NET MVC Identity extending vs replacing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I asked to architect a pretty complex application on ASP.NET MVC. It will include a personal account (Authorization) with a lot of related objects like:

```
PresentationLayer.UserAccount : IdentityUser {
     virtual ICollection<InnerPaymentCard> cards {get;set;}
     virtual ICollection<InnerServiceUsageRecord> cerviceRecords {get;set;}
     virtual ICollection<InnerInsuranceUsageRecord> insuranceRecords {get;set;}
     virtual UserRating rating {get;set;}
}
```

Moreover, the registration process will be separated into 2 steps : registration and confirmation by SMS code. Also for each service like **InnerPaymentCard** user must provide additional registration (subscription for service).

Should I use standart Indentity and extend it with 10+ one-to-many relations and with complex BLL or it is reasonable to write own Indentity service? If so, where could I learn about implementing own-writed identity (registration, authorization, subscription to services) on ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Does default solution meets your requirements?

In my experience, authentication and authorization of a system, which is complex enough, is beyond the scope of default implementation. How complex your system is?

According to your question, extending default solution with entities with primary keys to default entity does not add much of complexity. But most likely you will have lazy loading enabled. Otherwise too much data will be loaded on each request (or not loaded at all and you will need to load it by yourself anyway).

Make a complete list of requirements you have. Also it could be a good idea to add requirements, that could possibly appear later (talk to your customer about it). Then, list cons and pros for both solutions, default one and your own. This will help you to choose.